# How to get related videos of a YouTube video (with YouTube Data API)

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

*This question is also directed to the YouTube Data API support, because according to Google, support for the tags youtube-api, youtube-data-api and youtube-v3-api is provided here [Source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support). But any help is of course welcome!*

For a research project we need the function to **find and show related videos of a YouTube video**. The term "related videos" includes videos of similar category and content. Therefore, we want to use the YouTube Data API. The API parameter `relatedToVideoId` sadly got deprecated and removed. We, for example, have a video ID, and want to get *n* related videos. The languages used to fetch data are JavaScript (client) and PHP (server).

**So:** Is there a way of getting related videos of a YouTube video with an YouTube Data API call today? Or is there another way without the Data API?

Thank you for your help and let us know if there is anything unclear!

Comment: **This question is also directed to the YouTube Data API support** We are not youtube support.  If you want support directly from them you will need to contact them.   Regardless of what they have put on that Page I can say i have never in 10 years on the sight seen anyone from google support YouTube API

Comment: This here is the **only** way to get support for the YouTube Data API from Google. This is why the creation of this post on stackoverflow is **necessary**. 
_"We support the YouTube Data API on Stack Overflow. Google engineers monitor and answer questions with the youtube-api, youtube-data-api, and youtube-v3-api tags."_ [Source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support)

Comment: Don't believe everything you read online.   YouTube Doesn't own SO.  we are not YouTube support. There is no YouTube API support

Comment: Can you please give us your suggestion as to how we should proceed instead if we are not to ask any questions here in that regard? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question says you are looking for answer from YouTube support